# Graphileon gives error : "Could not connect. Connection error check your settings."

Tags: neo4j, graphileon

So I have been trying to use Graphileon for my Neo4j graph db. I have my Neo4j service set up and running. But when I try to start Graphileon and connect to my Neo4j db, it keeps saying "Could not connect. Connection error check your settings." even when all of the settings entered, are correct. I tried reinstalling Neo4j, I tried reinstalling Graphileon, but to no avail. I am using Neo4j Community edition, and Graphileon personal edition, on Ubuntu 18.04.
Is there something I'm missing? Is there some configuration that I'm missing for Graphileon?

[image: Graphileon Error screenshot]

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: Neo4j Community version 4.0.2

Comment: Neo4j 4.* support is not (yet) there.. Next version of Graphileon Personal Edition will have that.

Answer (score 0):

Graphileon 2.7.1 is available now, with support for Neo4j 4.0 . You can request a download link from here https://graphileon.com/request-graphileon-application/